# how to commit image to the application android

Tags: android, android-input-method

I want to commit image(Like smilies) from keyboard to other application(Like in Facebook) in my android application.I know to commit a text, we use commitText() method of InputConnection Class like this:

```
InputConnection ic = getCurrentInputConnection();
ic.commitText("Some String Value", 1);
```

Can someone tell me how to commit an image in same way?

Comment: image from keyboard is emoj code . I think it's text too. no difference

Comment: How to convert this Text into Emoji...

Comment: Have you checked new API 
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/image-keyboard.html